# Partial effect in non-linear regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

If I have estimated a non-linear regression model

$$y_t = f(x_t,\theta) + e_t$$

then how can I calculate the average partial effects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The partial effect is defined as

$$\frac{\partial f(x_t \theta)}{\partial x_{tk}}$$

so the average partial effect is simply

$$\frac{1}{T} \sum_t  \frac{\partial f(x_t, \theta)}{\partial x_{tk}}$$

calculated using the estimate $\hat \theta$.

Comment: Upvoted for high speed correct answer.